# Inhibit project creation outside Cloud Identity organization

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workspace, google-cloud-iam

I've a Cloud Identity Org mapped to a Google Cloud Platform Org.

The IAM policy on GCP Org is the following:

- "Admins" can create project and make administrative ops
- "Devs" can browse

In GCP Org is all ok, but I've seen that a "Devs" user can create a project outside the GCP Org.
Is there a configuration to prevent this behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, it seems to be a glitch after user creation. Yesterday, after 1 hour of the "Devs" user creation he could create projects outside GCP Org, now  he can't no more

Answer (score 0):

If you own the account you can [limit that access](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#predefined_roles).